# Invertible of the derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$  is $C^1$ and $\|Df(x)-\text{id}_{\Bbb R^2}\|< 0.00001$ for all $x$, then is $Df(x)$ invertible?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to see if I can determine the determinant of Df(x) but couldn't find anything useful. The fact that $\|Df(x)-\text{id}_{\Bbb R^2}\|< 0.00001$ means that Df(x) must be very close to the identity matrix, I got a feeling that the determinant shouldn't be close to 0, but couldnt solve it numerically.

Comment: Look up the von-Neumann-series, the geometric series for operators. It is not necessary to take 0.00001 as bound, $\|A-I\|<1$ is sufficient for $A$ being invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more direct way to think about it.

If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and $\|A-I\|<1/2$, then $A$ must be invertible. Why? If it weren't, we would have a unit vector $x$ with $Ax=0$. What do you then know about $(A-I)x$? What does this tell you about $\|A-I\|$?